# The depletion layer in thermal equilibrium

Tags: homework-and-exercises, solid-state-physics, schroedinger-equation

This question is from problem 29.1 from Ashcroft-Mermin.

I am given the following ODE:
$$\psi''(x) = K^2(\sinh \psi - \Delta N(x) / (2n_i))$$

I assume that $\psi << 1$, s.t $\sinh \psi \approx \psi$.

So I get the following ode:
$$\psi'' = K^2[\psi-\Delta N(x)/(2n_i))$$

Now, in the text it's written that the solution to the last ODE is:
$$\psi(x) = \frac{K}{2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty dx' e^{-K|x-x'|}\frac{\Delta N(x')}{2n_i}$$

I don't see how to get this ansatz, really.

I first need to solve the homogeneous ode of $\psi''-K^2\psi=0$, which is $\psi(x) = Ae^{Kx}+Be^{-Kx}$, but then how to solve the inhomogeneous ODE?

Comment: Ah, wait a minute you solve it with a fourier transform, I think.

Comment: have you heard of convolution and Green's function? see the example in  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function

Comment: @hyportnex how do I find this Green function in this case if I don't know the operator $D$ here?

Comment: of course, you know the operator, those are the things that have the $\psi$ in them.

Comment: @hyportnex these are the boundary conditions; what are they? I don't see it mentioned in the textbook.

Comment: your boundary conditions are in the $\pm \infty$

Comment: Are these BCs actually $\psi(\pm \infty)=0$?

Comment: yes, I believe so.

Comment: It doesn't seem to yield an appropriate solution, after $LG=0$ I get the solution: $G(x,x')=A(x')e^{Kx}+B(x')e^{-Kx}$; if indeed $D\psi=0$ were $\psi(\pm \infty)=0$, then I would get that from $DG=0$ $G\equiv 0$, since $K>0$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57204/discussion-between-hyportnex-and-mathematicalphysicist).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Green function can be obtained by solving the equation
$$
   G''(x)-K^2G(x)=\delta(x)
$$
being $\delta(x)$ the Dirac distribution. This is the proper definition. The general solution of this can be obtained by writing
$$
   G(x)=a\cdot\theta(-x)e^{Kx}+b\cdot\theta(x)e^{-Kx)}
$$
being $a$ and $b$ two constant to be fixed and $\theta(x)$ the Heaviside step function. Putting this into the equation yields
$$
G''(x)-K^2G(x)=-K b \delta(x) - K a \delta(x) + b \delta'(x) - a \delta'(x)=\delta(x).
$$
So, it is $b=c$ and $b=-1/(2K)$. So, finally
$$
   G(x) = -\frac{1}{2K}\left[\theta(-x)e^{Kx}+\theta(x)e^{-Kx}\right].
$$
I think you can start from here.

Comment: Isn't it $G=G(x,x')$? how do I retrieve the relation with $x'$?

Comment: Yes, you should apply the definition $\psi(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}G(x-x')(-K^2\Delta N(x')/(2n_i))dx'$. That's all. Please, note that you have translation invariance in the equation of the Green function.